# Redirecting a user

Tags: c#, mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

When the user clicks the first button ('Back to List' button), I redirect the user to the Employee List page. Can you please review this and suggest if there is any better way of achieving the same?

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Employee", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "editEmployeeForm" }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(emp => emp.FirstName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(emp => emp.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(emp => emp.LastName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(emp => emp.LastName)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Employee")'">Back to List</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
    </div>
}
```

I am concerned about the first button, however if you have feedback for any other code as well, please mention that.

Comment: You could replace the button with an anchor tag and use the Url helper to create the back url.
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Employee")">Back to list</a>

Answer (score 5):

Semantically, HTML button tags are supposed to *represent a user's action*, whereas the link tags are supposed to take care of the *navigation between pages*.

That said, as @user1320170 pointed out in comments, your tag should be a link (< a > tag.)

You'll notice it's much clearer this way.

Apart from that, your code is good, using `@Url.Action("Index", "Employee")` is a good plan.